# Is there a way of setting dimensions of sizedbox according to dimensions of my device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I want to set dimensions of `sizedbox` in accordance with the dimensions of device, in simple words, i want to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*constant` for my `SizedBox()`.

If there is another alternative to this, then please enlighten me with it's info.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the device dimension from `MediaQuery.of(context).size` and create a sized box based on that.
`SizedBox.fromSize({Key? key, Widget? child, Size? size})`
Creates a box with the specified size.

Alternate: you can make use of `flutter_screenutil` package also. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Answer (score 0):

Not mine, is from a youtube video

```
            import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        
        class SizeConfig {
          static  late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
          static  late double screenWidth;
          static late double screenHeight;
          static late double defaultSize;
          static late Orientation orientation;
        
          void init(BuildContext context) {
            _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
            screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
            screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
            orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
          }
        }
        
        // Get the proportionate height as per screen size
        double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
          double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
          // 812 is the layout height that designer use
          return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
        }
        
        // Get the proportionate height as per screen size
        double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
          double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
          // 375 is the layout width that designer use
          return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
        }
```